# removing non ascii characters does not work using '.encode('ascii','ignore')'. Replaces the characters with 'b\' instead of simply removing them

Tags: python, encoding, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I want to remove non ascii characters from a column. I am using the code:

```
 df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

It is changong '©lekd' to b'lekd'. Not only this, it is also changing all other values in the row to b'(column value)' (i.e. starting with 'b' and keeping the rest of the characters within single quotes). Can you tell me a way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: you are encoding to a byte string, following this logic you'd need to decode back to a string

Comment: I tried df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.encode('ascii','ignore').decode('ascii') but it is converting it back to ©lekd

Comment: © is an [ascii character](https://theasciicode.com.ar/)

Comment: @bn_ln No, it is not; the resource you link to is confused.

Comment: apologies - that is a bad link

Answer (score 0):

You can encode column headers to byte-strings back to remove non-ascii characters (including ©) as follows;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'©lekd':[1,2,3]})
renamings = dict((col, col.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')) for col in df.columns)
df = df.rename(columns=renamings)
print(df)
```